# how to DB design in mysql for multi user but diffrent data

Tags: php, mysql

how to DB design in mysql for multi user with different each user data.

For Ex. I have a 4 type of user with different data required for insert user profile, including user name and password.

Comment: users, types, type_fields, user_type_fields may be a good start. but your question hasn't enough data to be answered, and seems a lot a "Give me the code" question.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1 :**

In the table containing user profiles, have a user-type field as well.

**Approach 2 :**

Have a usertypes master table, with a usertypeid. And have a usertypeid field in the users table to indicate which type a user is. If a user can belong to multiple types, then you may either

(a) need to have a separate table to link userids and usertypeids,

*or*

(b)have the usertypeid field have a comma separated list of values of usertypeids to which a user belows.